# grafana data source option not visible

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, grafana

I started to work on grafana and i am not able to find the data source option on my drop down menu of grafana. Can somebody tell me where i am wrong. I followed the documentation of installation provided by grafana.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple - you are not logged in as "admin" and your user obviously does not have "admin" role.

But this has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.